# Nginx multiple ports under one server

Tags: nginx

I have:

- Nginx running on public IP: `123.456.78.910`
- Node.js app 1 running on: `localhost:8081`
- Node.js app 2 running on: `localhost:8082`

Both Node.js apps use websockets.

I would like it so:

- `123.456.78.910` shows some generic `index.html` file
- `123.456.78.910/projecta` goes to `localhost:8081`
- `123.456.78.910/projectb` goes to `localhost:8082`

I am not sure whether I just need `location <PATH> {}` or the idea of server blocks/virtual hosts, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04, or alias.

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/html;

        location /projecta {
                rewrite ^/projecta(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /projectb {
                rewrite ^/projectb(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`location` blocks can exist only within `server` or other `location`, so you don't need to remove `server`.

Assuming you want to serve some static context, you need to add one more `location` block:

```
location / {
    root   /var/www/html; # better to move from 'server' as it's not used in any other 'location'
    index  index.html;
}
```

As for `rewrite ^/projecta(.*) /$1 break;` - it simply cuts out `/projecta` substring from the URI. I.e. if you send request to `123.456.78.910/projecta`, nginx will proxy this request to `http://127.0.0.1:8081`.

Was this the purpose of adding that line? If so, instead of using `rewrite` I'd recommend you to add the trailing slash to the address specified in `proxy_pass`:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
```

Otherwise, with this `rewrite` directive you'll see probably unwanted behavior: if you send request to `123.456.78.910/projecta/whatever`, nginx will proxy this request to `http://127.0.0.1:8081/whatever`.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question to be more clear. I *think* I need the `location /projecta` and `location /projectb`? I probably don't need the `location /`, but just a `root /var/www/html`; to serve a generic `index.html file` at `/`? My Node.js apps actually have websockets, so I think I need what you mentioned in #3?

Comment: @adamt32 Please check the updated answer. Yes, `proxy_http_version` and `proxy_set_header`s are required for proxying websocket traffic.

Comment: Works almost perfectly besides one small issue. What would be the problem if: I can hit `123.456.78.910:8082` with the exposed port, but the `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082/;` doesn't fully load? As in I can see the site, but the requests do not resolve. Very close.

Comment: @adamt32, not sure I understood the question.. According to your nginx config, 123.456.78.910 shouldn't be available on port 8082. Can you describe problematic scenario step by step?

Comment: I made a new question for this more specific problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556250/node-js-app-doesnt-load-when-location-path-is-not