# Node.js app doesn't load when location path is not /

Tags: node.js, nginx

For some reason, my Node.js app running on `127.0.0.1:8081` requires `/`.

If I start with this, **BOTH `/` and `/projectb` are able to load the page**.

```
server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /projectb {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
```

When I change it to this, `/projectb` is no longer able to fully load the page. When I look at the network tab, some *(but not all)* requests fail, for example some images, .js, some wrong endpoints.

```
server {
        listen 80;

        location /somethingelse {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /projectb {  # I'd expect this to still work.
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
```

To summarize, it works when I hit the port directly `123.456.78.910:8081`, and when I have BOTH `/` and `/projectb` proxy to `http://127.0.0.1:8081/`, and when I proxy to `/` by itself, but not when I proxy to `/projectb` by itself.

Why might this be the case?

Comment: You need to make sure the app expects the path to be `/projectb`, else the CSS and JS files path generated may be wrong. Or else you need to handle those paths in Nginx itself

Comment: Any advice on how to make sure the Node.js app expects the path to be `/projectb`? I shouldn't have to change the Node.js code, should I? I thought the proxy was just supposed to take care of this, so when I hit nginx `123.456.78.910/projectb`, it requests my Node.js app running on `127.0.0.1:8081`.

Comment: You can use html `<base>` tag in your files to specify the base path as `/projectb`, or you should serve the static files directly through nginx instead of node then you can server those without the `/projectb` path.

Answer (score 0):

If `location /projectb` doesn't work without `location /` then it means that `location /projectb` is not configured properly. Have you tried removing `location /projectb` to see if it works with just `location /`?

What endpoint your nginx should proxy requests to? Is it `http://127.0.0.1:8081/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8081/projectb`? I have a feeling that it's `http://127.0.0.1:8081/projectb`.

Please try to remove the trailing slash from `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;` line in the second snippet.

Comment: Yes, it works with just `location /`.

It should proxy to `127.0.0.1:8081/`.

When I remove the trailing slash from the second snippet, the page doesn't load at all (404 Not Found).

Comment: @adamt32, can you specify the full URL of the request you're making? if it's  `http://123.456.78.910/projectb` then `location /` rule should proxy it to `127.0.0.1:8081/projectb` and not to just `127.0.0.1:8081/`.